# MySQL Improvement with rounded Primary Datetime Keys

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm working on a query to join multiple tables from one database by first rounding their primary datetime keys. The database contains percistance data from openhab and every table only has a primary Datetime row called Time and a value row called Value. As the date gets written small delays of one sec can occure and im not able to directly compare the primary keys. Here's what I got so far:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i1.Time)+30)DIV 60)*60) AS rounded_time,i1.Value,i2.Value,i4.Value,i5.Value 
FROM item1 i1,item2 i2,item4 i4,item5 i5
WHERE
(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i1.Time)+30)DIV 60)*60) = (((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i2.Time)+30)DIV 60)*60) AND
(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i1.Time)+30)DIV 60)*60) = (((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i4.Time)+30)DIV 60)*60) AND 
(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i1.Time)+30)DIV 60)*60) = (((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i5.Time)+30)DIV 60)*60) AND 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i1.Time) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day));
```

This query already takes 4 seconds and merging one more item already bursts my server.

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB4fE.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANrAv.png)

[Explain Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3ygN.png)

**EDIT 1:**
I managed to get resonable Results with the following joins by allowing an Offset of 60 seconds in both directions (Not even shure if both are needed):

```
SELECT date_format(item1.Time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS TIME,item1.Value AS I_TEMP,item2.Value AS I_HUM,item4.Value AS I_PRESS,item5.Value AS I_LIGHT,item6.Value AS O_HUM,item7.Value AS O_TEMP,item8.Value AS O_PRESS
FROM item1
LEFT JOIN item2 ON (item2.time BETWEEN item1.time AND date_add(item1.time, interval 60 SECOND)) OR (item1.time BETWEEN item2.time AND date_add(item2.time, interval 60 SECOND))
LEFT JOIN item4 ON (item4.time BETWEEN item1.time AND date_add(item1.time, interval 60 SECOND)) OR (item1.time BETWEEN item4.time AND date_add(item4.time, interval 60 SECOND))
LEFT JOIN item5 ON (item5.time BETWEEN item1.time AND date_add(item1.time, interval 60 SECOND)) OR (item1.time BETWEEN item5.time AND date_add(item5.time, interval 60 SECOND))
LEFT JOIN item6 ON (item6.time BETWEEN item1.time AND date_add(item1.time, interval 60 SECOND)) OR (item1.time BETWEEN item6.time AND date_add(item6.time, interval 60 SECOND))
LEFT JOIN item7 ON (item7.time BETWEEN item1.time AND date_add(item1.time, interval 60 SECOND)) OR (item1.time BETWEEN item7.time AND date_add(item7.time, interval 60 SECOND))
LEFT JOIN item8 ON (item8.time BETWEEN item1.time AND date_add(item1.time, interval 60 SECOND)) OR (item1.time BETWEEN item8.time AND date_add(item8.time, interval 60 SECOND))
WHERE
item1.Time > date_sub(now(), interval 3 HOUR)
```

Also INDEXING is working as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqL3N.png) and querytime is rather short thanks to Rick James.

Comment: how many row do you have in the tables and which MySQL version you are using

Comment: at most i have 11k atm and i would like to combine atleast 8 of them

Comment: Im Using 5.7.21 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Before tackling the question, I am **dubious about the validity** of it.  If I have 08:09:29 versus 08:09:31, they are only 2 seconds apart, but your "rounding" technique will say that they are different.  You need something like `TIMEDIFF(...) < 30` to avoid that 'bug'.

To address your **performance** problem...  This can't use any index:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i1.Time) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day));
```

By changing to this:

```
i1.Time > now() - interval 1 day
```

You can use this:

```
INDEX(Time)
```

And that will *probably* speed up the query.

But...  There is a **worse problem**.  You are doing a "cross join".  This means that *all* combinations of rows in the 4 tables are compared.  If there are only 1000 rows in each, the combination is *one trillion*!

Perhaps you need `JOIN ... ON ...`?

Comment: How do you join on timediffs ?    
JOIN item2 ON TIMEDIFF(item1.Time,item2.Time) < 30 ?

Comment: Don't `ON`, use `WHERE`, like you were doing.